# wordpress rss feed multiple tags

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, rss

I would like to change **WordPress**'s `RSS` feed functionality to only match posts and pages that has all of the tags (not just one) when I specify multiple tags. I've already added code to include pages on top of posts.

Example URL: `~WP~/feed/?tag=holiday,halloween`

I'm trying to alter the query inside the `pre_get_posts` action hook.

Code:

```
if ($_GET['tag']) {
    $tagsArray = explode(',', $_GET['tag']);

    array_push($query->tax_query, array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $tagsArray,
        'operator' => 'AND',
    ));
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to make the query match all of the tags? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Posting so others who's in the same situation can solve it.

```
if ($_GET['tag']) {
    $tagsArray = explode(',', $_GET['tag']);

    if (sizeof($tagsArray) > 1) {
        $query->set('tag__and', $tagsArray);
    }
}
```